# If I have been deported and banned from the US, can I travel through US airspace?

Tags: usa, air-travel, deportation

I was deported from and banned for life from the USA. I have been traveling through South America seeing different countries. I'm currently living in Peru and want to travel to Europe. One way to travel would be flying through US airspace, to Canada.

My main question is: can I pass through US airspace on my way to Canada as part of a flight to Germany?

Are there are other alternatives to travel from Peru to Europe while avoiding North America all together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a U.S. Visa if I'm traveling nonstop from Mexico City to Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72287/do-i-need-a-u-s-visa-if-im-traveling-nonstop-from-mexico-city-to-canada)

Comment: @Giorgio the history of deportation distinguishes this question from the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Any idea how this would be handled if the plane needed to divert in-flight and landed in the US? I know there are procedures to clear those who would need a visa to enter the US and don't have them in such an instance, but if someone is banned for life?

Comment: @Richard That's a separate question, but the general practice is you wouldn't be allowed to leave the airport (i.e. pass through customs). While played up for drama, it was the plot of [The Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminal) which was [based on a man stuck in a France airport for 18 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri)

Comment: The history of deportation doesn't change the fact that the _answer_ is the same.

Comment: @Machavity You mean "pass through immigration". Immigration decide who can come into the country; customs decide how much tax they owe.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In the US we tend to use them interchangeably, since both immigration and customs are handled in the same area by the same government agency.

Comment: @WGroleau Users find answers here by searching for questions.  The deportation makes this a substantially different question.

Comment: I find answers by typing a question and examining the AI-suggested duplicates.  Almost always, none of them are even close, but since the search feature is even more useless than the AI, I post it.  And in a very short time, someone finds the duplicate that the AI did not find.  :-)

Comment: Quite a few places in South America fly to Amsterdam with KLM

Comment: How did you get banned for life?

Comment: Now I see why they have banned you...

Answer (score 40):

The airline will collect *Secure Flight* information when checking you in, but there is no restriction preventing you from flying over US airspace just because you're inadmissible to the US.

So you'll be fine - you just need the documents for transiting Canada and entering Germany.

Comment: Interesting claim that Air Canada or LATAM or whatever would collect Secure Flight information on a flight that doesn't land in the US. I almost challenged you to provide a source, but my gosh, a little Googling says you're right, so you've got my upvote instead! I never would have guessed.

Comment: @jackal Russia does that too AFAIK

Comment: The US [goes somewhat further than that](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180879/requesting-a-copy-of-the-us-secure-flight-overflight-table).

Answer (score 37):

Flying over USA airspace is not a problem. What *is* a problem is that Canada, like the USA but unlike many other countries, requires you to have a transit visa *in advance*. Peru is *not* on the list of [visa-exempt](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html) countries. The Canadian authorities may know that you were deported and banned from the United States, and if so, I think your chances of getting the Canadian visa are reduced. You should apply in advance, and as other answers mention, you should be prepared to book instead through airports where you will not have this problem.

Comment: And, even if your country were on the list of visa-exempt countries, you'd still need to get an eTA (similar to the US ESTA) before transiting Canada unless you're a U.S. citizen or fall under a few other minor exemptions.

Comment: Is a transit visa required (or easier to get) if you never actually enter Canada? Depends of course on whether the airport layout allows for that.

Comment: Looks like it is: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=420&top=16

Answer (score 15):

You cannot land in the US (does not matter if it is only a transit). However, I am not seeing any issues with getting a flight to Canada. You need to have in the mind that you will need to land in Canada. So, maybe, you will need a Visa+ for that.

Could you go to Europe avoiding US or Canada?

Yes, you can... You could go to Brazil and get a flight to Portugal, for example.

Comment: yeah I read online that you can't stop at USA i don't want to stop i just want to fly pass, on my way to Canada.

Comment: yeah but for some reason the booking places just keep throwing USA  my way, i really just want to avoid it all together.

Comment: @peruviantraveler DOn't worry about it

Comment: @peruviantraveler "for some reason the booking places just keep throwing USA my way": try excluding US airlines from your search, or limiting your search to Latin American and Canadian airlines.  Also look for a way of eliminating codeshare flights.

Comment: There are non stop flights from Lima to at least Amsterdam, London, Paris, Madrid and Barcelona. If you allow a single connection, you can probably get to every major European city without having to cross the US.

Comment: Google flights at least will give you a list of connecting airports and let you deselect the ones you don't want.

Comment: This new "buy it online on booking engines" tomfoolery is not the only way...  Try buying a ticket the old fashioned way, through a travel agent.

Comment: ITA Matrix allows you to exclude operating carriers (even if it's marketed by another airline.) If you wanted to exclude American, United, and Delta, for example, you'd enter "-OPAIRLINES AA UA DL" in the "extension code" fields.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would fly direct from Guatemala to Madrid. Or From San Pedro Sula to Barcelona.  Or from Panama to Amsterdam. I'm from the UK and can fly to the US without a visa, but due to bad mannered people in the US airports I now avoid flying through the US whenever possible. I'd rather invest my money in countries who treat me nicely. On the Spanish route I have never had any hassle from anyone. It's worth the extra cost.

Airlines you want to look at include KLM, Iberia, Air Europa, British Airways.

I've never had any difficulties in Canada and the people are friendly, but they can be quite strict and it adds an extra complication to your trip. As far as airspace is concerned it doesn't matter about the US at all. The Canadians have a deal with the US to manage those flights. Probably easiest to avoid US and Canada

Comment: Much of this answer seems to consist of personal opinions and anecdotes that are of no relevance to the question at hand.

Comment: @Mico OP explicitly asked for alternatives to a route over or through North American countries. John M's stated reason for knowing these alternatives adds credibility, even though no sources are cited. The reasons may not be relevant, but they explain a perfectly valid other reason why someone wouldn't want to travel there.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek - Please re-read my comment. I would have thought that it was clear that my comment wasn't directed at the advice that the OP should look at the offerings of KLM, Iberia, etc. Instead, it was directed at JohnM's comments about how he [she?] feels about the treatment allegedly received at some US airports. That's what I believe falls in the category of "personal opinion and anecdote". I fail to see how personal, likely heart-felt but also utterly unverifiable, anecdotes make a positive contribution to the OP's understanding of his/her travel options.

Comment: Why not fly KLM straight from Peru to Amsterdam, or Iberia to Madrid? Why does everyone suggest going to another South American country first?

Comment: @Mico I'm sorry for the harshness of my comment, you are correct in your original assessment. I've upvoted your comment, but I'll still let mine stand, as others might jump to the same conclusion I did - that you were criticizing the post as a whole, insead of the opinionated and anecdotal reasons for it.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would avoid flying over US airspace at all costs.
All it takes, is for the flight you're on to land in the US for whatever reason and your then in trouble.
Trust me, I've been deported from the US to Canada (Canadian Citizen) and tried flying to Mexico, and was detained.

Follow the advice from John M, it'll be money well spent!

Comment: (-1) You were detained by: 1) whom 2) where 3) under what conditions? When an unforeseeable stopover occurs ([force majeure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_majeure)]), inadmissible persons (assuming no arrest warrant exists) will simply be detained within the airport until the next possible flight which the airline is required to provide. One would not get into 'trouble' (as you claim) because there was no intention to enter the US. Kindly refrain from (wishful thinking) horror scenarios and rephrase your answer based on facts.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The user is **brand new** to Stack Exchange, can you be a bit more welcoming and reasonable? *The user does not need to say where they were detained and by whom.* You can just say that you think the traveler will not get in trouble and that you think they'll simply be sent back home, and leave it at that.